# pythoncom module not found (pywin32 is installed) - with a Python2.7 virtual environment

Tags: python, import, module, pythoncom

I need to set up a Windows 64-bit PC Virtual Environment with Python 2.7 to run a script that I didn't write, 
and I'm not entirely sure the usage it has, but it imports pythoncom (a .NET communication module as far as I could understand).

It seems that the module **exists** in pywin32 and pypiwin32 (installed both),
I can see the module is installed in the environment when typing "pydoc modules" and "pydoc pythoncom", but it still fails to import the module when running the script.

I can only use pywin32-244,
it has a .dll named pythoncom27.dll inside its wheel file,
I can't seem to find a workaround, 
anyone knows why it might happen?
(all of the versions I gave are not optional (for python, the package) - I cannot change them they has to remain the same)

Furthermore - In newer versions of python3.x it's running fine. 
from the python CommandLine I can actually import it! 
any reason for me to be able to import it and see it in all of the mentioned ways and still not to be able to import it via a script? maybe something wrong with the script or the way im running it?

Also might be important - the script that gives the error is just imported through another script,
so I'm actually running T1.py which then imports T2.py which gives the error when trying to import pythoncom...

Thanks in Advance!
Oren

Comment: It seems that when running the scripts from the computer without a virtual environment it works just fine, so I checked the sys.path output right before the importing and it found that when running on the actual computer there are some added paths to it, im looking into it right now..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasn't using the virtualenv to run the script,
after activating the virtualenv, typing in the cli "script.py"
will execture the script from the system's default python env, even though it says (Venv) in the cli,
To run it in the Venv's python environment you need to type in 'python script.py'

Oren